# Task :app:installDebug FAILED in React native

Tags: react-native, build.gradle

After i build apk and set, enableProguardInReleaseBuilds and enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture to TRUE. I always failed to build my React native project.

Here is the message on the terminal.

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
>   Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
>
> Task :app:installDebug
>   10:19:56 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>   10:19:56 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   10:19:56 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
>   10:19:56 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   10:19:56 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   10:19:56 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/ahroidlife/Documents/react-native/lab/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
>   10:19:56 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   10:19:57 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
187 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 184 up-to-date
Unable to install /Users/ahroidlife/Documents/react-native/lab/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

Here is my screenshot :
1. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZflP.jpg)
2. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRVHF.jpg)
3. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVN2f.jpg)

Comment: 1) did you do `./gradlew clean` on android folder ? 2) do you have an android emulator running ?

Comment: Yes, run `gradlew clean` by changing to `android` folder! This solves the issue in most cases!

Comment: Yeah, i was try to running the command ./gradlew clean.

Comment: Here is my new screenshot, https://imgur.com/IiBwDqE

Comment: By the way, It's was solve. I try to delete debug.apk in ./app/build/outputs/debug.apk

Thanks